# QTableView item selection based on a QStandardItem data attribute

Tags: python, pyqt, selection, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

What would be the most efficient and technically (**Python/PyQt4**) correct way of making arbitrary muti-selection in a **QTableView** which has a model encompassing hierarchy of `QStandardItems` (a graph plot data) with custom `isSelected` data attribute added per item.

In details: Along with the table I have a matplotlib plot which outputs ranges (`isSelected` attribute comes directly from these ranges) that correspond to my `QTableView` data and I want to add a bit of interaction between these two gui elements.

i.e matplotlib plot selection is reflected in `QTableView` and vice versa (which I'm getting by hooking selection change to reading corresponding indexes and feeding them back to graph plot).

Hopefully this explanation makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, right now you have your QTableView.selectionChanged() feeding the selections back to your matplot. The most efficient approach would be to have your matplot emit a signal for its selection, with the relevant items.

A table view already stores its selections in a QItemSelectionModel, so as far as I can see it would be redundant and unnecessary to store your own isSelected attribute on the items. Your matplot view should know the items it is using and should be able to notify the table view of its selection changes.

Your matplot view can have a signal that you emit, such as `selectionChanged(items)`, and can continue having no knowledge of the table view.

Your table view, as it already knows about the matplot view, can connect to its `selectionChanged(items)` to the matplot and listen for selection changes. Even if your table is also emitting a signal and has no knowledge of the matplot, you can make the connection in whatever parent class does know of them both.

This is why I think the attribute isn't needed: The only way to make use of that attribute is to scan the entire model, checking each item. Thats not really efficient. The selection should happen in reaction to the signal being emitted.

```
myMatPlotView.selectionchanged.connect(myTableView.matplotSelected)
```

And in your `matPlotSelected()` slot, you can use the selection model to set the items selection:

**tableView**

```
def matPlotSelected(self, qStandardItems):

    selModel = self.selectionModel()
    model = self.model()

    for item in qStandardItems:
        idx = model.indexFromItem(item)
        selModel.select(idx, selModel.Select)
```

**Update**

In the comments you provided a code snippet, which really helped to isolate what you want to achieve.

*Your example*

```
def __init__(self):
    super(myDialog, self).__init__()
    self.t = QtGui.QTreeView()
    self.m = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.t.setModel(self.m)
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.t)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.l = [
        ['one', False], ['two', True], 
        ['three', False], ['four', True], 
        ['five', False]]
    self.populate()

def populate(self):
    self.m.clear()
    root = self.m.invisibleRootItem()
    for item in self.l:
        e = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        e.setText(item[0])
        root.appendRow(e)
```

If this is your actual situation, then what I suggested above fits in like this:

```
def populate(self):
    self.m.clear()
    root = self.m.invisibleRootItem()
    selModel = self.t.selectionModel()
    for item in self.l:
        e = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        e.setText(item[0])
        root.appendRow(e)

        if item[1]:
            idx = self.m.indexFromItem(e)
            selModel.select(idx, selModel.Select)
```

Comment: That's the actual point I wanted to clarify. As far as I know there are two possible selection options. First, I provide a `QRect` area for `setSelection()` (which is irrelevat to my case) or, second, I porivide `QModelIndex`es for my `QTreeView's selectionModel()`, but I do not know those indexes unless I iterate through all model elements to identify them. The question is how to get model's indexes only for those 'tagged' items I want to select.

Comment: @decuman: There might be a disconnect between us on what your real problem is. I just updated my example to show how to convert items to indexes. Does that solve the problem? Your matplotview should know the items already and be sending them in the signal.

Comment: Sorry for confusion: In more short and abstract fashion: There is a data array (a list) with some elements tagged as 'selected' which populates a hierarchical `QStandarItemModel`. How to get those items tagged as 'selected' to become selected on `QTreeView` initialization?

Comment: @decuman: It seems to me like you are skirting around the same issue. Selection is the same regardless of whether it takes place inside the init of the TreeView or in a slot that fires at a later date. Wherever you are populating your model, you will have the items right there and you can check their "isSelected" attribute. The you just use the selection approach listed above. Are you wondering how to filter that data list? And yes...I am confused.

Comment: Yes. probably my case is related to just filtering data. Here is a quick code snippet [*CODE*](http://pastebin.ca/2143606). There is a list with True/False selection states that I want to select on QTableView init.

Comment: @decuman: Ok, so seeing a code example now gives me something to comment on. See updates.

Comment: That was the answer! I knew it has to be simple.Thanks very much.